# compilation error saying "conflicting types for ‘check’"

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

```
 /**
 * Return an array of arrays of size *returnSize.
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */

      struct node{
      char data[3];
      struct node* next;
      };
      int** threeSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int* returnSize) {
            int i,j,k;
            struct node* head=NULL;
            struct node* current=NULL;
            struct node* temp=NULL;
            for(i=0;i<numsSize-2;i++){
                for(j=i+1;j<numsSize-1;j++){
                    for(k=j+1;k<numsSize;k++){
                       if((nums[i]+nums[j]+nums[k])==0){
                           **bool ans=check(&nums[i],&nums[j],&nums[k],head);**
                           if(ans==false){
                               temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                               temp->data[0]=nums[i];
                               temp->data[1]=nums[j];
                               temp->data[2]=nums[k];
                               temp->next=NULL;
                               if(head==NULL){
                                  head=temp;
                                  current=head;
                        }
                        else{
                            current->next=temp;
                            current=temp;
                        }
                   }
                   else if(ans==true){
                       continue;
                   }
               }
            }
        }
    }
    return head;
}

     **bool check(int a,int b,int c,struct node* head){**
         while(head!=NULL){
              if(head->next[0]==a && head->next[1]==b && head->next[2]==c){
                 return false;
              }
              else{
                 return true;
              }
              head=head->next;
       }
}
```

I think I am missing something about reference parameters here

Comment: Head=head->next will never be called (that's not the error)

Comment: Move the implementation of `check` above your implementation of `threeSum`, or properly prototype your function. If your compiler did *not* warn you about an "implicit declaration" of function `check` returning `int`, you need to crank up your warning levels to pedantic. Once you make the *real* declaration available to `threeSum`, an entirely different error (parameter type mismatch) should reveal itself, but that's another issue.

Answer (score 1):

As per the definition of `check()`, you just need to pass values not pointers to `check()`. In line

```
bool ans=check(&nums[i],&nums[j],&nums[k],head);
//-------------^
```

remove `&` for `nums[i]` and others.

Answer (score 0):

Given the prototype of `check` as:

```
bool check(int a,int b,int c,struct node* head)
```

the call

```
bool ans=check(&nums[i],&nums[j],&nums[k],head);
```

is wrong. It should be (drop the `&`s):

```
bool ans=check(nums[i], nums[j], nums[k],head);
```

Also, provide a declaration of `check` before you call it from `threeSum`.

```
bool check(int a,int b,int c,struct node* head);

int** threeSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int* returnSize) {
  ...
}
```

Otherwise, the compiler will make assumptions about input types and the return type of `check`.

Comment: Still the same error :( @RSahu I actually tried ur option before.